# My add thousands comma function doesnt work

Tags: javascript

I have a function that converts a value to a value with a thousands comma, and it works with one of my other html forms, but not this one. Can anyone see a problem with my code?

---javascript---

```
function numberWithCommas(x) {
      return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  }
  function calcule2(){
  var i=0; for (i=0;i<= 29;i++) {calcule();}}
  function calcule(){

  var C20 = Excel2Html.C20.value=+parseFloat(Excel2Html.C19.value)*parseFloat(Excel2Html.E16.value)*4;
var C21 = Excel2Html.C21.value=+parseFloat(Excel2Html.C20.value)*0.22;

Excel2Html.C20.value=(numberWithCommas(C20));
Excel2Html.C21.value=(numberWithCommas(C21));
```

---html---

```
<input type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="E16" value="100" size="5" style="background: #67823A; border: none; color: #ffffff;">
<input type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="C20" value="196000" size="5" disabled="disabled">
<input type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="C21" value="43120" size="5" disabled="disabled">
```

C20 returns - 196000
C21 returns - 43120

However, it should be:

C20 = 196,000
C21 = 43,120

Comment: your `numberWithCommas` function seems to work just fine

Answer (score 2):

There are already methods for formatting numbers in the way you're looking for.

You can use [toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)

```js
function numberWithCommas(value) {
    return Number(value).toLocaleString("en");
}

document.querySelector("#number").addEventListener("input", function() {
  console.log(numberWithCommas(this.value));
});
```

```html
<input type="number" id="number" />
```